# leafsync strange behaviour - duplicate maps when syncing two different maps

Tags: r, leaflet, mapview

I have a bizarre thing going on with `leafsync::sync`. I have two maps generated using `mapview` function in r. The underlying data is in `sf` format

**map1**
[image]

**map2**
[image]

As you can see they are two different maps with different legends. But when I try to put them together using `leafsync::sync` the first map is duplicated instead of the second map (the legends are different though).

`leafsync::sync(map1,map2)` produces the following map
[image]

and `leafsync::sync(map2,map1)` produces the following map
[image]

This has never happened before and I am creating some other simple maps using `leafsync::sync` and they are absolutely fine. I have tried installing `leaflet` and `leafsync` and it didn't help. This issue is driving me crazy. Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?